# Why is SQL Server trying to convert my nvarchar(20) datatype to an int?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting the "conversion" error in a SQL Select query.

The error is:

> Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   The conversion of the nvarchar value '7000952682' overflowed an int column.

Problem is, there are no int columns in my table!

Here is the table structure:

[image]

Here is the query:

[image]

If I set the value of `@SU` to `NULL`, then it does return all rows as expected. When the value is set to the string value of '7000952682' I get the error.

Why is SQL Server trying to convert the nvarchar value to an int?

Comment: It looks like the CASE statement is trying to CAST the value from the table for the SU column to an int. Is there a way to confirm this and force it to keep the nvarchar value to compare with the other nvarchar value (instead of trying to cast it/them to integers)?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All branches of a `CASE` expression have to have the same type.  In this case (no pun intended), it looks like SQL Server is using an integer type and doing an implicit cast of `SU` to integer.  The problem is that the max value for an integer in SQL Server is roughly 2.1 billion, and the example you gave is using the value `7000952682`, hence the overflow.

You have two options here.  You could make everything `varchar`:

```
CASE WHEN @SU IS NULL OR @SU = '' THEN '1' ELSE [SU] END
```

Or, you could make everything numeric, using a type that won't overflow, e.g.

```
CASE WHEN @SU IS NULL OR @SU = ''
     THEN CAST(1 AS numeric(20, 6))
     ELSE CAST([SU] AS numeric(20, 6)) END
```

As a side note, you could write the first part of your `CASE` expression more succinctly using `COALESCE`:

```
CASE WHEN COALESCE(@SU, '') = '' THEN '1' ELSE [SU] END
```

Comment: Changing the  "THEN 1" to "THEN '1'" fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `case` in the `where` clause.  The logic is more simply and *accurately* expressed as:

```
where (@su is null or @su = '' or @su = su)
```

Comment: While Tim's answer explains the problem correctly, this answer is better IMHO, since it shows a better option to the entire where clause.,It can even be better still using `isnull(@su, '') = '' or so = @su`. +1 for both.